# Breadth First Search (BFS) And Depth First Search (DFS) Code - Need suggestion on how can I improve it further

Tags: algorithm

I have written BFS and DFS code purely with my understanding as below. Which is along with the test example. Looking for the input - how I can make it better in terms of logic & data Structure. I know there are already cooked & may be perfect code in the internet but I wish to attempt mine.

PS: Code is not perfect however I have tested on given example. Apology if you find it messy. Your comments will be welcomed.

```
package com.company.graph;

import java.util.*;

public class BrethFirstSearch {


    public static void main(String...args){


        /*
         Input Undirected Graph -

            2      4       1
        A-------B-------C-------D
        | \             |   \   |
      7 |  \9         13|   3\  |6
        |   \           |     \ |
        E----F----------G-------H
          1      8         13

        Task 1 - Represent this graph as Data Structure that have optimal Space & Time complexity for store & traversal
        Task 2 - Perform "Breadth First Search"


        Simplified Representation of Graph where replaced vertex names with numbers..
             2      4       1
        0-------1-------2-------3
        | \             |   \   |
      7 |  \9         13|   3\  |6
        |   \           |     \ |
        4----5----------6-------7
          1      8         13

        */


        // We store number instated of letters since in real world every vertex may have full qualified name ex - "LasVegas" instead of just "A"
        Map<Integer,String> vertices = new HashMap<>();
        vertices.put(0,"A");
        vertices.put(1,"B");
        vertices.put(2,"C");
        vertices.put(3,"D");
        vertices.put(4,"E");
        vertices.put(5,"F");
        vertices.put(6,"G");
        vertices.put(7,"H");

        Map<Edge, Integer> edges = new HashMap<>();

        //Note - I have store both the side to make Graph search simpler. Comments will be welcomed!!
        edges.put(new Edge(0,1), 2);
        edges.put(new Edge(0,4), 7);
        edges.put(new Edge(0,5), 9);
        edges.put(new Edge(1,0), 2);
        edges.put(new Edge(1,2), 4);
        edges.put(new Edge(2,1), 4);
        edges.put(new Edge(2,3), 1);
        edges.put(new Edge(2,6), 13);
        edges.put(new Edge(2,7), 3);
        edges.put(new Edge(3,2), 1);
        edges.put(new Edge(3,7), 6);
        edges.put(new Edge(4,0), 7);
        edges.put(new Edge(4,5), 1);
        edges.put(new Edge(5,0), 9);
        edges.put(new Edge(5,4), 1);
        edges.put(new Edge(5,6), 8);
        edges.put(new Edge(6,2), 13);
        edges.put(new Edge(6,5), 8);
        edges.put(new Edge(6,7), 13);
        edges.put(new Edge(7,2), 3);
        edges.put(new Edge(7,3), 6);
        edges.put(new Edge(7,6), 13);


        breadthFirstSearch(vertices, edges);
        depthFirstSearch(vertices,edges);

    }


    static void depthFirstSearch(Map<Integer,String> vertices, Map<Edge, Integer> edges){

        System.out.format("%n%n%n%n************  Depth First Search - DFS ***********%n%n");

        LinkedList<Integer> listOfVertex = new LinkedList<>(vertices.keySet());
        List<Edge> listOfEdges = new ArrayList<>(edges.keySet());

        Stack<Integer> dfsStack = new Stack<>();


        while (!listOfVertex.isEmpty()){

            Integer v = listOfVertex.getFirst();
            dfsStack.push(listOfVertex.remove());

            System.out.format("*** Start DFS from Vertex %S ***%n", vertices.get(v));

            while(!dfsStack.empty()){
                Integer vO = v;
                for (Edge edge: listOfEdges) {
                    if (v.equals(edge.getV1()) && listOfVertex.indexOf(edge.getV2()) != -1){  // found new vertex
                        Integer nextV = edge.getV2();
                        System.out.format("  Searching from Vertex %S -----> %S%n", vertices.get(edge.getV1()), vertices.get(nextV));
                        dfsStack.push(nextV);
                        listOfVertex.remove(nextV);
                        v = nextV;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(vO.equals(v)){   //means not new vertex found from current vertex
                    v = dfsStack.pop();     //Search for previous vertex
                    System.out.format("Vertex %S has been conquered %n", vertices.get(v));
                }
            }

        }

    }



    static void breadthFirstSearch(Map<Integer,String> vertices, Map<Edge, Integer> edges){

        System.out.format("************  Breadth First Search - BFS ***********%n%n");

        LinkedList<Integer> listOfVertex = new LinkedList<>(vertices.keySet());
        List<Edge> listOfEdges = new ArrayList<>(edges.keySet());

        BfsQueue bfsQueue = new BfsQueue();
        bfsQueue.add(listOfVertex.remove());  //start from 1st vertex = 0 alias A

        while (!bfsQueue.isEmpty()){

            //remove and start search from this vertex
            Integer v = bfsQueue.remove();
            System.out.format("Vertex %S has been conquered %n", vertices.get(v));

            //Search the Vertices from v
            listOfEdges.
                    forEach(edge -> {
                        if(v.equals(edge.getV1()) && listOfVertex.indexOf(edge.getV2()) != -1){
                            bfsQueue.add(edge.getV2());
                        }});

            //Mark the Searched Vertex
            Iterator<Integer> i = bfsQueue.getIterator();
            while (i.hasNext()){
                Integer vertex = i.next();
                if (listOfVertex.remove(vertex)){
                    System.out.format("     Searching from Vertex %S ------> %S %n", vertices.get(v), vertices.get(vertex));
                }

            }
        }
    }




    static class BfsQueue {

        private LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

        Iterator<Integer> getIterator(){
            return list.iterator();
        }


        Integer remove(){
            Integer v = null;
            if(!list.isEmpty()){
                v = list.getFirst();
                list.removeFirst();
            }
            return v;
        }

        void add(Integer v){
            list.add(v);
        }

        boolean isEmpty(){
            return list.isEmpty();
        }

        boolean isPresent(Integer v){
            return list.indexOf(v) != -1;
        }

    }


    static class Edge {

        int v1;   //1st vertex
        int v2;   //2nd vertex

        public Edge(int v1, int v2) {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
        }


        public int getV1() {
            return v1;
        }

        public int getV2() {
            return v2;
        }
    }
}
```

The Output is :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=64975:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\CodeBase\Test\out\production\Test com.company.graph.BrethFirstSearch
************  Breadth First Search - BFS ***********

Vertex A has been conquered 
     Searching from Vertex A ------> E 
     Searching from Vertex A ------> B 
     Searching from Vertex A ------> F 
Vertex E has been conquered 
Vertex B has been conquered 
     Searching from Vertex B ------> C 
Vertex F has been conquered 
     Searching from Vertex F ------> G 
Vertex C has been conquered 
     Searching from Vertex C ------> H 
     Searching from Vertex C ------> D 
Vertex G has been conquered 
Vertex H has been conquered 
Vertex D has been conquered 




************  Depth First Search - DFS ***********

*** Start DFS from Vertex A ***
  Searching from Vertex A -----> E
  Searching from Vertex E -----> F
  Searching from Vertex F -----> G
  Searching from Vertex G -----> H
  Searching from Vertex H -----> C
  Searching from Vertex C -----> D
Vertex D has been conquered 
Vertex C has been conquered 
  Searching from Vertex C -----> B
Vertex B has been conquered 
Vertex H has been conquered 
Vertex G has been conquered 
Vertex F has been conquered 
Vertex E has been conquered 
Vertex A has been conquered 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This is more of a question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [concurred](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concurred)

Answer (score 0):

One approach I tried is  - Implemented edges as a Map where each entry has key as a vertex and value as a List containing edges i.e. all connecting vertices along with the weight. (I inspired through adjacency list approach over the internet and is more efficient than edge list as per my previous approach specially while searching connecting vertices from a 
given vertex. The complexity of traversal could be n(n-1) i.e. O(n^2) in Edge List  approach assuming all vertices connected to all vertices. Where as (n-1) i.e. O(n) in adjacency list approach as in n vertices graph n can be connected to all n-1 vertices)

i.e. if below is the graph -

```
             2      4       1
        0-------1-------2-------3
        | \             |   \   |
      7 |  \9         13|   3\  |6
        |   \           |     \ |
        4----5----------6-------7
          1      8         13
```

then the map looks like -

```
        Map<Integer, List<Edge>> verticesEdges = new HashMap<>();
        verticesEdges.put(0, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(1,2), new Edge(4,7),new Edge(5,9) )));
        verticesEdges.put(1, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(0,2),new Edge(2,4))) );
        verticesEdges.put(2, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(1,4),new Edge(3,1),new Edge(6,13), new Edge(7,3))));
        verticesEdges.put(3,new LinkedList<>(List.of( new Edge(2,1), new Edge(7,6))));
        verticesEdges.put(4, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(0,7),new Edge(5,1) )));
        verticesEdges.put(5, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(0,9), new Edge(4,1),new Edge(6,8) )));
        verticesEdges.put(6, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(2,13), new Edge(5,8), new Edge(7,13))));
        verticesEdges.put(7, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(2,3),new Edge(3,6),new Edge(6,13))));
```

Now the BFS and DFS code require minor modification. I have presented below just for verification perspective -

```
package com.company.graph;

import java.util.*;

public class GraphSearch {

    public static void main(String...args){


        /*
         Input Undirected Graph -

            2      4       1
        A-------B-------C-------D
        | \             |   \   |
      7 |  \9         13|   3\  |6
        |   \           |     \ |
        E----F----------G-------H
          1      8         13

        Task 1 - Represent this graph as Data Structure that have optimal Space & Time complexity for store & traversal
        Task 2 - Perform "Breadth First Search"


        Simplified Representation of Graph where replaced vertex names with numbers..
             2      4       1
        0-------1-------2-------3
        | \             |   \   |
      7 |  \9         13|   3\  |6
        |   \           |     \ |
        4----5----------6-------7
          1      8         13

        */


        // We store number instated of letters since in real world every vertex may have full qualified name ex - "LasVegas" instead of just "A"
        Map<Integer,String> vertices = new HashMap<>();
        vertices.put(0,"A");
        vertices.put(1,"B");
        vertices.put(2,"C");
        vertices.put(3,"D");
        vertices.put(4,"E");
        vertices.put(5,"F");
        vertices.put(6,"G");
        vertices.put(7,"H");

        //Implemented edges as a Map where for each entry -  key is a vertex and value is List containing edges i.e. all connecting vertices along with the weight !!
        Map<Integer, List<Edge>> verticesEdges = new HashMap<>();
        verticesEdges.put(0, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(1,2), new Edge(4,7),new Edge(5,9) )));
        verticesEdges.put(1, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(0,2),new Edge(2,4))) );
        verticesEdges.put(2, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(1,4),new Edge(3,1),new Edge(6,13), new Edge(7,3))));
        verticesEdges.put(3,new LinkedList<>(List.of( new Edge(2,1), new Edge(7,6))));
        verticesEdges.put(4, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(0,7),new Edge(5,1) )));
        verticesEdges.put(5, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(0,9), new Edge(4,1),new Edge(6,8) )));
        verticesEdges.put(6, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(2,13), new Edge(5,8), new Edge(7,13))));
        verticesEdges.put(7, new LinkedList<>(List.of(new Edge(2,3),new Edge(3,6),new Edge(6,13))));


        breadthFirstSearch(vertices, verticesEdges);
        //depthFirstSearch(vertices,verticesEdges);

    }


    static void depthFirstSearch(Map<Integer,String> vertices, Map<Integer, List<Edge>> verticesEdges ){

        System.out.format("%n%n%n%n************  Depth First Search - DFS ***********%n%n");

        LinkedList<Integer> listOfVertex = new LinkedList<>(vertices.keySet());

        Stack<Integer> dfsStack = new Stack<>();


        while (!listOfVertex.isEmpty()){

            Integer v = listOfVertex.getFirst();
            dfsStack.push(listOfVertex.remove());

            System.out.format("*** Start DFS from Vertex %S ***%n", vertices.get(v));

            while(!dfsStack.empty()){
                Integer vO = v;
                for (Edge edge: verticesEdges.get(v)) {
                    if (listOfVertex.indexOf(edge.getV()) != -1){  // found new vertex
                        Integer nextV = edge.getV();
                        System.out.format("  Searching from Vertex %S -----> %S%n", vertices.get(v), vertices.get(nextV));
                        dfsStack.push(nextV);
                        listOfVertex.remove(nextV);
                        v = nextV;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(vO.equals(v)){   //means not new vertex found from current vertex
                    v = dfsStack.pop();     //Search for previous vertex
                    System.out.format("Vertex %S has been conquered %n", vertices.get(v));
                }
            }

        }

    }



    static void breadthFirstSearch(Map<Integer,String> vertices, Map<Integer, List<Edge>> verticesEdges){

        System.out.format("************  Breadth First Search - BFS ***********%n%n");

        LinkedList<Integer> listOfVertex = new LinkedList<>(vertices.keySet());

        BfsQueue bfsQueue = new BfsQueue();
        bfsQueue.add(listOfVertex.remove());  //start from 1st vertex = 0 alias A

        while (!bfsQueue.isEmpty()){

            //remove and start search from this vertex
            Integer v = bfsQueue.remove();
            System.out.format("Vertex %S has been conquered %n", vertices.get(v));

            //Search the Vertices from v
            verticesEdges.get(v).forEach(edge -> {
                if(listOfVertex.indexOf(edge.getV()) != -1){
                    bfsQueue.add(edge.getV());
                }});

            //Mark the Searched Vertex
            Iterator<Integer> i = bfsQueue.getIterator();
            while (i.hasNext()){
                Integer vertex = i.next();
                if (listOfVertex.remove(vertex)){
                    System.out.format("     Searching from Vertex %S ------> %S %n", vertices.get(v), vertices.get(vertex));
                }

            }
        }
    }




    static class BfsQueue {

        private LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

        Iterator<Integer> getIterator(){
            return list.iterator();
        }


        Integer remove(){
            Integer v = null;
            if(!list.isEmpty()){
                v = list.getFirst();
                list.removeFirst();
            }
            return v;
        }

        void add(Integer v){
            list.add(v);
        }

        boolean isEmpty(){
            return list.isEmpty();
        }

        boolean isPresent(Integer v){
            return list.indexOf(v) != -1;
        }

    }


    static class Edge {

        int v;   //Connecting Vertex
        int w;   //weight Of edge

        public Edge(int v, int w) {
            this.v = v;
            this.w = w;
        }

        public int getV() {
            return v;
        }

        public int getW() {
            return w;
        }
    }
}
```

When I have ran it -

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=50287:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\CodeBase\Test\out\production\Test com.company.graph.GraphSearch
************  Breadth First Search - BFS ***********

Vertex A has been conquered 
     Searching from Vertex A ------> B 
     Searching from Vertex A ------> E 
     Searching from Vertex A ------> F 
Vertex B has been conquered 
     Searching from Vertex B ------> C 
Vertex E has been conquered 
Vertex F has been conquered 
     Searching from Vertex F ------> G 
Vertex C has been conquered 
     Searching from Vertex C ------> D 
     Searching from Vertex C ------> H 
Vertex G has been conquered 
Vertex D has been conquered 
Vertex H has been conquered 




************  Depth First Search - DFS ***********

*** Start DFS from Vertex A ***
  Searching from Vertex A -----> B
  Searching from Vertex B -----> C
  Searching from Vertex C -----> D
  Searching from Vertex D -----> H
  Searching from Vertex H -----> G
  Searching from Vertex G -----> F
  Searching from Vertex F -----> E
Vertex E has been conquered 
Vertex F has been conquered 
Vertex G has been conquered 
Vertex H has been conquered 
Vertex D has been conquered 
Vertex C has been conquered 
Vertex B has been conquered 
Vertex A has been conquered 

Process finished with exit code 0
```